# I have a problem when running Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I have Android Studio 3.1. I am trying to open a project, but I get the error "Failed to find target with hash string 'android-25'". Below the error message I see a link "Install missing platform(s) and synch project". If I click this link, I get another error, which says

```
"The following packages are not available: - Package id platforms;android-26".
```

Comment: Welcome to SO niki. You'll need to download API-25 (or maybe 26) from SDK manager. Please add a screenshot of your current SDK packages or the project `build.gradle` dependencies + minsdkversion or compileSdkversion.

Comment: I do not have API 25 in Sdk manger

Comment: You’ll need to install it then. Check SDK platform 25 then it will start to download the package. Perhaps you didn’t install any packages on SDK manager yet?! Am I right?

Comment: Go to SDK Manager option from the toolbar and select the Android 7.1.1 (Nougat) -> check the "Android SDK Platform 25" then press ok to install the missing platform tool. Hope this will help you?

Answer (score -2):

[image]

```
Duplicate class kotlin.collections.jdk8.CollectionsJDK8Kt found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.6.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.6.21)
Duplicate class kotlin.internal.jdk7.JDK7PlatformImplementations found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.6.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.6.21)
Duplicate class kotlin.internal.jdk7.JDK7PlatformImplementations$ReflectSdkVersion found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.6.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.6.21)
Duplicate class kotlin.internal.jdk8.JDK8PlatformImplementations found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.6.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.6.21)
Duplicate class kotlin.internal.jdk8.JDK8PlatformImplementations$ReflectSdkVersion found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.6.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.6.21)
Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.ExperimentalPathApi found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.6.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.6.21)
Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathRelativizer found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.6.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.6.21)
Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathsKt found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.6.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.6.21)
Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathsKt__PathReadWriteKt found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.6.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.6.21)
Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathsKt__PathUtilsKt found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.6.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.6.21)
Duplicate class kotlin.jdk7.AutoCloseableKt found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.6.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.6.21)
Duplicate class kotlin.jvm.jdk8.JvmRepeatableKt found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.6.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.6.21)
Duplicate class kotlin.random.jdk8.PlatformThreadLocalRandom found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.6.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.6.21)
Duplicate class kotlin.streams.jdk8.StreamsKt found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.6.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.6.21)
Duplicate class kotlin.streams.jdk8.StreamsKt$asSequence$$inlined$Sequence$1 found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.6.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.6.21)
Duplicate class kotlin.streams.jdk8.StreamsKt$asSequence$$inlined$Sequence$2 found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.6.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.6.21)
Duplicate class kotlin.streams.jdk8.StreamsKt$asSequence$$inlined$Sequence$3 found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.6.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.6.21)
Duplicate class kotlin.streams.jdk8.StreamsKt$asSequence$$inlined$Sequence$4 found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.6.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.6.21)
Duplicate class kotlin.text.jdk8.RegexExtensionsJDK8Kt found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.6.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.6.21)
Duplicate class kotlin.time.jdk8.DurationConversionsJDK8Kt found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.6.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.6.21)
```

Go to the documentation to learn how to Fix dependency resolution errors.